# Beginner-friendly sources for learning relevant UX

Tags: ux-field, guidelines, human-interface-guideline, resources, examples

First off I'd like to say that I'm not completely sure if this violates any policies as I can't find any UX-specific "Ask question" practices. So if I do violate any rules, I'd happily delete this.

I'm currently learning quite a lot about UI/UX/IXd from the questions that are asked and answered here, but I was hoping to get some further material that might be relevant to those fields.

I've got a UX exam coming up shortly and the book we are using is [Interaction Design: Beyond HCI](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n0h9CAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions). Having read around about the book online it doesn't seem to be held into all too high regard in the community, so even though I own it and About Face (which seems a lot better and more well-received) I was hoping to get some further material.

Basically my question is if anyone here have good sources that cover a **broad range** of basic UX/UI; so any particularly important paradigms to learn about etc. Or if anyone has a good source of UX exercises that could be relevant to a ***general*** exam in UX.

I understand this question leaves room for highly subjective answers, but hopefully it might lead to some a good *discussion* and some highly *relevant* answers that might help any **further beginners** who might wish to learn about UX to understand more about the field.

Comment: Just for beginning, I can recommend you to start with https://medium.com/tag/ux. I think there are a lot of good articles.

Comment: Read this sequence of blog postings by Joel Spolsky: It's not just a 'how to guide' - it makes you 'think UX' http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html.  And with a bit of extra material it's also a recommended book on the recommended books list.

Comment: There's An Answer on recommended books on here if you go hunting for it...

Answer (score 0):

This is purely based on my experience and I did my CUA certification recently from HFI (http://humanfactors.com/training/index.asp). UX is a process and involves lots of steps including understanding requirements, user research, analysis, IA, and building the interactive wireframes (wireframes - low / medium and high), visual designing and testing. If you pick-up the material randomly on the internet, you might get good information about the topics or best practices but not as a whole. If you are serious about UX, think about a certification which gives you complete picture on the UX process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you do a quick edit with a link to where you got your certification from in case someone who just browses past would be interested?

Comment: Sure, done. please let me know if more information is required. Thank you.

Comment: I'll go ahead and wait a few days to see if there will be any further discussion before I mark any answers. It's my hope that this perhaps could become a sticky for beginners as a sort of source to help them on their journey. Thanks for the answer! :)